# Show that the function $g$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1],f(0)=0$ and $f^{'}(x)$ is finite for each $x\in (0,1)$.

> Show that if $f^{'}$ is increasing on $(0,1)$ then so is the function $g$ defined by $g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$

**My try**:$g^{'}(x)=\dfrac{f^{'}(x)x-f(x)}{x^2}$.

If I can show that $g^{'}(x)>0\forall x$ then we are done.But I am unable to show that .

Please help by giving some hints.

Comment: Try to use the mean value theorem : $f(x)=f(0)+xf'(\theta x)$ with $0<\theta<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $$g(x)=\int_0^1 f'(tx)\,dt.$$ Then indeed $f(x)=x·g(x)$. And for $x<y$ and thus $tx<ty$ for all $t>0$: $$g(y)-g(x)=\int_0^1 (f'(ty)-f'(tx))\,dt\ge0.$$

Comment: How to show $g$ increasing from here

Comment: @Amartya: By directly computing the function value difference.